# How to save a file on shared space in Cordova with Android?

Tags: android-file, cordova-plugin-file

I am using Apache Cordova with `cordova-plugin-file` to develop some android app. Since Android API 29 (Android 10), [apps no longer have access to shared](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStorageDirectory()) space directly due to privacy issues.

I was storing some pdf file on `file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/` from where the user could then open the pdf file.

```js
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL('file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/', function (dir) {
  dir.getFile(filename, { create: true }, function (file) {
    file.createWriter(function (fileWriter) {
      console.log('Writing content to file')

      fileWriter.onwriteend = function () {
        console.log('Successful file write...')
      }

      fileWriter.onerror = onerror

      fileWriter.write(DataBlob)
    }, onerror)
  }, onerror)
}, onerror)
```

But that stopped working on Android 10.

How can I store now a file to be accessible by the user?

Answer (score 3):

> window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + "/Download" used to work

- This should work as is when targeting API 28 (now forbidden by Google Play)
- This should work when targeting API 29 with the dev version of the plugin (which has the `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`), alternatively you can use the [edit-config](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/spec.html#edit-config) to add this flag.
- This won't work when targeting API 30, as API 30 ignores the `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage` attribute.

It's important to read the [Android Notes](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases#migrate-legacy-storage) before you target API 30. You may need to migrate your files to another folder to maintain access to them when targeting API 30 using the new APIs. [Source](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/issues/426#issuecomment-756757287).

#### Solution for up to Android 10 (API 29)

Use the dev version of the plugin

```
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-file
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file.git
```

I tested it and it allows me to use `cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + "/Download"` in Android 10 (API 29)